# What is wrong in this assembly code, conditional jmp

Tags: assembly, intel

In the below intel assembly code, I use a cmp (compare) instruction before a conditional jump, but for below code, it should not jump but it does & prints the string.

What is going wrong.(Flat assembler, Win-7 x32).

```
ORG 100h
USE16


        mov ah, 09
        mov dx, message
        cmp ah, 10d
        je condjmp


condjmp:
        int 21h

        mov ah,01
        int 21h

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h

 message db 'conditional jump', 0Ah, '$'
```

Comment: is there anything between je and the label? Maybe it's just falling through?

Comment: I've never programmed x86 assembly, so maybe I'm way off base, but if there are no instructions between `je condjmp` and the actual `condjmp` address, won't `condjmp` be executed either way?  Or is there code after the `je` instruction that you did not include?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jump goes to a label that is immediately following the jmp instruction, so it does not matter if the jump is taken or not, you always end up at the label.

Comment: Yes it was kind of falling through. Adding a 'return' equivalent mov ah,4ch , int21 helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Goldenmean, like Simon said to you,

If you follow the logical FLOW of your program you will find that in both cases of the conditional jump, the next instruction executed right will be:

int 0x21

I mean,

If JE not true ---> next instruction = int 0x21
if JE true -------> next instruction = int 0x21

Hope this was clear enough for you.